# Bug in CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableCreateMergeCommand

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm using the .NET SDK for Kusto.  I have a `TableSchema` object in which I specify a folder.  However that folder is ignored in the create command produced by `CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableCreateMergeCommand()`.  Where should I file the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an additional function named GenerateTableCreateMergeCommandWithExtraProperties() - which generates command that includes docString and folder.
Please use it instead.